# matrix multiplication can't be compile

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, compiler-warnings

I have some trouble when compiling this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <time.h>

int perkalianMatriks(double ** A, double ** B, double ** C, int n);
int randomMatriks(double * m, int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int n_order = 0 , i, j;
    double ** A, ** B, ** C;
    time_t time1, time2;
    double diff_sec;

    randomMatriks(double * m, int n)

    A = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double) * n_order);
    B = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double) * n_order);
    C = (double **) malloc(sizeof(double) * n_order);

    for (i = 0; i < n_order; i++) {
        A[i] = (double *) calloc(sizeof(double), n_order);
        B[i] = (double *) calloc(sizeof(double), n_order);
        C[i] = (double *) calloc(sizeof(double), n_order);
    }

    printf("\nMatrix Sizes : ");
    scanf("%d", %n_order);


    time(&time1);
    perkalianMatriks(A, B, C, n_order);
    time(&time2);
    diff_sec = difftime (time2,time2);


    printf ("Total time to execute %f seconds.\n", diff_sec);
    return 0;
}

int randomMatriks(double * m, int n) {
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n_order; i++) {
        m[i] = (double) (rand() % 10) + 1;
    }
}

int perkalianMatriks(double ** a, double ** b, double ** c, int n) {
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            c[i][j]=0;          
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
            {
                c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error when compiling

1. sekuensial.c(16): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before
   'type'
2. sekuensial.c(16): error C2198: 'randomMatriks' : too few arguments
   for call
3. sekuensial.c(16): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
4. sekuensial.c(29): error C2059: syntax error : '%'
5. sekuensial.c(45): error C2065: 'n_order' : undeclared identifier

Does anyone can help me fix this?

Comment: scanf("%d", %n_order); needs to be scanf("%d", &n_order);

Comment: yes, i've changed it. Sorry, typo.. and then the error?

Comment: What is an [incomplete] declaration of `randomMatriks` doing in the middle of your `main` function? You already declared `randomMatriks` before `main`. Why did you decide to do it again inside `main`???

Comment: @AndreyT I mean, it's to call function randomMatriks (to make a matrix randomly)

Comment: The program now compiles. If you are having problems debugging it, that's a different question.

Comment: @sinta: A *call* to a function does not look like that. You already call `perkalianMatriks` in your code and you do it correctly, so you must know what what a *call* looks like. Why does your "call" to `randomMatriks` look so much different? If you want to *call* `randomMatriks`, then go ahead and *call* it, instead of attempting to *redeclare* it.

Comment: Additionally, the first batch of memory allocations do not make sense at all. The size is calculated incorrectly. To avoid such errors, stop casting the results of `malloc` and stop using type names in `sizeof`. Your `malloc`s should look as follows: `A = malloc(n_order * sizeof *A); B = malloc(n_order * sizeof *B);` and so on.

Comment: Additionally, C language does not guarantee that `calloc` will correctly initialize a `double` array with zeros. It will work on IEEE754 systems, but it is still a hack. SInce you are going to re-initialize the matrix anyway, forget about `calloc` and use normal `malloc` for all allocations.

Comment: @AndreyT I've changed the code.. The error now when it's debugging. still can help me? :)

Comment: I've rolled back the question contents to original form so answers match.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a semi-colon. And you can't name a variable `double`. I guess this line should just be removed, since it is a cut and paste of the declaration above. If you need to call it, you should call it with real arguments. I don't see that you defined anything suitable for the first parameter, I guess from later on in your code, you intend to use `n_order` for the second parameter.

```
randomMatriks(double * m, int n)
              ^^^^^^            ^^^
```

This `scanf` is wrong, you probably want `&`:

```
scanf("%d", %n_order);
            ^^^
```

The variable `dif_sec` doesn't exist. Typo.

```
dif_sec = difftime (time2,time2);
^^^^^^^
printf ("Total time to execute %f seconds.\n", dif_sec);
                                               ^^^^^^^
```

The variable `n_order` doesn't exist. `n` instead probably.

```
for (i = 0; i < n_order; i++) {
                ^^^^^^^
```

The `randomMatriks` should return something. It falls off without a `return` statement, even though it is declared to return an `int`.

You have some unused variables and function parameters.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
             ^^^^        ^^^^
    int n_order = 0 , i, j;
                         ^^^
```

Comment: so, it must be `randomMatriks(* m, int n);` ?

Comment: yes, i've changed it.. sorry, for the careless. now, remain 4 errors

Comment: okay, i'm sorry.. :) I'll leave the question. oh, can you help to call the admin to delete these question? thanks

Comment: @sinta: The question wasn't bad, you just shouldn't have been fixing it in the question. Fix it on your machine. When you have a new problem, ask a new question.

Comment: @sinta: Okay, I rolled back the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you never initialized your `C` array, which is an array of pointers to pointers to double. In `perkalianMatriks`, it's deferenced, and at that point, all bets are off as to what the pointer is (0xfdfdfdfd in your case).

(I'm guessing you might not understand what a `**` type really is and how it's supposed to be used?)

Comment: My answer was based on the fixed version of your code, which has now been rolled back to the original uncompilable version. :)

Comment: Oh, hah, no problem. I also agree with the fact that the original question should not be changing under the answers like that, so the original version should be the "live" version so that the answers don't make future people go "huh??" when they see this page.

Answer (score 0):

That is not correct way of allocating memory for **B and so on.
See example on allocating memory for double pointers (**B) and so for the rest of pointers.
Also take care of semi colons.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to perform multiplication of two matrices.

Your can get a simple clue at : [solvedc.com](http://www.solvedc.com/Codes/Entry.aspx?entryId=19)